# beginner need help can't get red square to show on window and window closes within seconds

Tags: python, pygame

I can get game window to show but no red square appears the window closes within seconds. I'm following this Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=crUF36OkGDw&list=PLkkm3wcQHjT7gn81Wn-e78cAyhwBW3FIc I have watched the video over and everything in my code seems like his in the video. I don't know how to fix this I am still learning pygame and python myself. Is this an error in my code? Or is it possible to be a problem with my setup?

```
EDIT: is traceback something to be worried about? because  I get 
two of them this one: Main.py", line 58, in <module>
g.new()
then this one: Main.py", line 17, in new
self.all_sprites = pygame.sprite.LayedUpdates()
AttributeError: module 'pygame.sprite' has no attribute 
'LayedUpdates
```

main.py

```
import pygame
from sprites import *
from config import *
import sys

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_WIDTH,WIN_HEIGHT))
        self.clock = pygame.time.clock()
        self.running = True
    
   def new(self):
        # a game starts
        self.playing = True

        self.all_sprites = pygame.sprite.LayedUpdates()
        self.blocks = pygame.sprite.LayedUpdates()
        self.enemies = pygame.sprite.LayedUpdates()
        self.attacks = pygame.sprite.LayedUpdates()

        self.player = Player(self, 1, 2)

    def main(self):
         # Game Loop
        while self.playing:
            self.events()
            self.update()
            self.draw()
            self.running = False
        
    def events(self):
        #Game Events Loop
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self.playing = False
                self.running = False 

    def update(self):
        # Game Loop Updates
        self.all_sprites.update()
    
    def draw(self):
        # Game Draw Loop
        self.screen.fill(BLACK)
        self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen) 
        self.clock.tick(FPS)
        pygame.display.update()
    
g = Game()
g.intro_screen()
g.new()
while g.running:
    g.main()
    g.game_over()

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

sprites.py

```
import pygame
from config import *
import math
import random

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y):
    
        self.game = game
        self._layer = PLAYER_LAYER
        self.groups = self.game.all_sprites
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
    
        self.x = x * TITLESIZE
        self.y = y * TITLESIZE
        self.width = TITLESIZE
        self.height = TITLESIZE
    
    self.image = pygame.Surface([self.width, self.height])
    self.image.fill(RED)
    
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.x = self.x
    self.y = self.y
    
    def update(self):
        pass
```

here is the config file if needed..

config.py

```
WIN_WIDTH = 640
WIN_HEIGHT = 480
TITLESIZE = 32
FPS = 60

PLAYER_LAYER = 1

RED = (255,0,0)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
```

Comment: The code inside `while g.running:` should be indented.

Comment: even after doing as you suggested same thing still happens no square and window closes

Comment: Try unindenting to all the lines from `g = Game()` until `sys.exit()`, you're putting them inside the `Game` class and it should be in the main scope. You can edit your post with these changes and see if it works.

Comment: that gives me a Expected indented block error, I have spent 5 hours watched the video 50 times my code lines up with his so I'm not understanding the issue maybe it's cause i am using vscode and he uses sublime?

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67854945/edit) with the changed code? About VSCode and Sublime, that's less likely to be the cause of your issue.

Comment: sorry i forgot to. U meant with the indented or the unindenting? sorry I am new to stackoverflow

Comment: I've posted an answer, see if it helps.

Comment: There are typos in your code `pygame.time.Clock()` instead of `pygame.time.clock()` and `pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()` instead of `pygame.sprite.LayedUpdates()`.

Comment: @StevenTurley When a question is solved, add an answer to the question, but don't edit the title with something like "(Solved)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating the code to be executed inside the `Game` class, therefore it's not being executed at all. Try unindenting the code so it'll look like this:

```py
class Game:
    # ...
   
# Remove four spaces from the beginning of all theses lines below 
g = Game()
g.intro_screen()
g.new()
while g.running:
    g.main()
    g.game_over()

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Also, I don't know if it's a copy-and-paste error, but the identation of your `Player` class is also wrong. Add four spaces to the code that goes from `self.game = game` until `self.y = self.y`, so it'll look like this:

```py
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y):
        # Add four spaces to all those lines below
        self.game = game
        self._layer = PLAYER_LAYER
        self.groups = self.game.all_sprites
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        
        # ...
    
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.x = self.x
        self.y = self.y
    
    # Keep this line as it is, because it's a method of the Player class
    def update(self):
        pass
```

Comment: think I've done what was asked, Sorry i am new to stackoverflow